# Java Average Length of Constructor

Tags: java, oop, constructor, coding-style

Sorry for posting a rather vague question here - but I've been struggling to find a definitive answer to this one - maybe there is none, but just thought asking fellow developers.

Last week, a colleague of mine mentioned that the length of constructors (In Java and in OOP in general) should be kept to a minimum. While I do agree the approach in general, he went on to say that it should be only a few lines - 3-4 lines at maximum.

I'm not sure how he arrived at this number and I wonder how useful that approach is. If you have some complex initialisation to perform, your constructors will exceed that limit. 
You can split and break and refactor your code into smaller functions till cows come home, I prefer to keep related code into one method and avoid un-necessary functions as it makes code more readable.
This at times does lead to situations where constructors are fairly moderate in size - 50-100 lines of code in worst scenarios, but then even if I break it up into functions, technically speaking, that code is still "called as part of initialisation". So, 100 lines of code might be replaced by a single function call, but that 100 lines still get called when you call the function?
I also looked at checks type default definitions and it has default constructor length set to 150, which sounds more reasonable "Than a few lines code".

Would love to know what you guys follow as rule of thumb or if there is, indeed, such a accepted upon limit.

Comment: This is an inherently subjective question.

Comment: The constructor tells you the state of an intialized object, keeping it short (and splitting long lines into methods) makes that easier.

Comment: Hi, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for asking those question. In general 100 lines seems a little to much for a constructor (for me). But anyway I find dividing in methods more readable, in fact if the methods are well named and work as expected, they become a summary of the initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Good rule of thumb is that any method (or constructor) should fit on one screen in your IDE so you don't have to scroll down when you are trying to read and understand what is this method doing (so it improves readability).

Nothing prevents you from making exception from time to time but you should generally split really long methods to smaller chunks because I've really seen methods few hundred lines long and it really made me cry when I had to change the code.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been struggling to find a definitive answer to this one - maybe there is none

You are right.  There isn't a definitive answer.  It is subjective.

> Would love to know what you guys follow as rule of thumb ...

I don't.  I use my judgement on a case-by-case basis.  Subjectively.

> ... or if there is, indeed, such a accepted upon limit.

There isn't.  You won't find any specified limits in the main-stream Java coding standards.  A decent coding standard won't be prescriptive about this because it is counter-productive.

On the other hand, this is the kind of situation where code reviews can be beneficial.  If you see an "overly long" constructor or method, it is worth pointing out, *especially* if there is a good refactoring available; i.e. one that your colleagues would agree improves readability.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a common practice but not anything. I have made classes that had a lot of code in constructors. I also had classes with no constructor. As mentioned above, there is no such thing that you should not contain a lot of code in constructors, and JVM loads them too.

So why this concept came up? It is because people think that constructors are for initializing variables in objects since they are called only when new instances are created. Also doing a lot of work in the constructors makes no point in using OOP principles. OOP itself means *'Object Oriented Programming'* which is meant to structure code as objects. So I'm leaving the conclusion to you. See the both examples and think which one is better.

***Example 1:***

```
public Dog(String name)
{
    System.out.println("Dog " + name + ": Bark!Bark!");
}
```

***Example 2:***

```
public Dog(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void bark()
{
    System.out.println("Dog " + name + ": Bark!Bark!");
}
```

In the first example, the dog barks only once, but in the second example, you can make the dog bark as many times as you want. And for this same reason, they say to use constructors only for initializing values.

Hope this helps.